# Manga about a city of murder between people with superpowers

Tags: area-d

Saw this manga one year ago, but I think it's not new, because when I starting reading it had already 70ish chapters, more or a bit less

Let's state what I remember:

- In the beginning there's some chapters on a ship that is transporting the people (with superpowers) to another city, where they will fight (I don't remember if there's a prize to the winner or how the winner is chosen, by killing or such things)
- One of them demonstrated his power, disassemble (or alike), and did that to a clock that he had with him (or someone gave it to him); His power did something similar to [this](http://smg.photobucket.com/user/sergiolorenzon/media/heb13.jpg.html)
- There's a girl that can pass through wall, but to do so, she needs to get naked
- And then, there's one guy I believe is the protagonist, his power is something like the protagonist from Charlotte (receive the powers of the person he possessed), but he doesn't need to possess the others, just touch them; If I'm not mistaken, some of the people on the ship are afraid of him
- There's a guy who can store almost anything in his pocket or his hair, because he stores things in another dimension
- There's some type of organization that wear an Owl head, or it's actually their head
- I remember another chapter where people get stuck in the walls of a building, action made by one of the "evil people with superpower" (I don't remember if it was a bad or a good character)

I'm not sure if the next things I'll state is about the manga I was talking above, I could be mixing with another manga

- There's a doctor in this city, though much hate him, the people (with superpowers) need him, because he's the only one who give them treatment to the wounds of the battles
- That doctor has a zombie assistant, a child

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the dismount power and maybe you could describe the main protagnists power a bit more for people who don't know Charlotte? Otherwise, this is a pretty nice description.

Comment: I added an example about the dismount power, I don't know how to describe what his power did, but an image should explain better what I mean

Comment: Oh, so something like [disassemble](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disassemble)?

Comment: Yes, that's it, I will change the description right now, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Area D - Inou Ryouiki**?

---

> *One of them demonstrated his power, disassemble (or alike), and did that to a clock that he had with him (or someone gave it to him)*

**Satoru Ida**

> **Watchmaker** (Dismantling, 時計師, Tokei Shi) is the name of Satoru's Altered ability. With it, Satoru is able to disassemble or unmake any object that comes into physical contact with his hands. His ability is indiscriminate; it does not matter the object's size, complexity of composition, or whether it is living or non-living - if Satoru touches it, it can be dismantled. After accidentally dismantling his mother, due to lack of control, and killing her, Satoru keeps his hands wrapped in bandages in order to minimize any possible, similar situation. At present, Satoru still has difficulty effectively controlling his ability.

---

> *There's a girl that can pass through wall, but to do so, she needs to get naked*

**Rio Ibuki**

> **Shadow Play** (シャドープレイ, Shadō Purei) Rio can project herself in a two dimensional realm and travel across the surface of any object (walls and human skin, for example) just like a shadow, hence the name. It seems she cannot extend her powers to objects as she is seen naked when she uses it. Also, when she travels off of human skin, enough force is applied to knock someone to the ground.

---

> *There's a guy who can store almost anything in his pocket or his hair, because he stores things in another dimension*

**Kaito Yuuki**

> Kaito's altered ability is known as **Deserted House** (廃屋) . It allows him to store objects of his choosing within another dimensional space. However, in order to store said objects, Kaito must come into physical contact with the object he'd like to store. In addition, he can only store as many objects as equal to the mass of his body. Objects stored by Kaito's ability maintain the same condition as they were when they came into contact with Kaito's body, i.e., an arrow exhibiting the same momentum and/or velocity as when it was released and shot or a canned beverage that was initially stored in a freezer at cold temperatures.

---

> *There's some type of organization that wear an Owl head, or it's actually their head*

[image]

My reference : http://aread.wikia.com/

Comment: Could you expand your answer to include why you believe it is Area D?

Comment: Edited my answer, quoted some of your states. My first post though. Haven't got familiar with this post environment. Sorry if you get the post messy